# Keplr mobile handle the click event to select the amount of coins available and the amount of staking on pie chart

Tags: react-native, blockchain, cosmos

[image]

On mobile devices, when an account has an available coin and is staking pie chart will be displayed.
Green for coins available and blue is for staking. I want to handle event when clicking on `available coin` or `staking` border on pie chart will show corresponding Tooltip.

Currently `keplr` uses `react-native-svg` to draw on mobile
[image]

I noticed that there are 2 pairs of tags `Use` and `Circle`. Each pair will draw a half circle, representing `coins available` and `staking`.

[image]

I add `onPress` to listen for click event, however `eventClick("first")` will always be run.
How can when I click on `second-arc` then `eventClick("second");` will run and when I click on `first-arc` then `eventClick("first");` will run ?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)